# Where does the contemporary measurement of a Kezayit come from?

Tags: halacha, food, shiurim-measurements, size, acharonim

According to the Nodeh B'Yehuda and the Chazon Ish, in order to calculate the size of a *kezayis* (which apparently is based on the size of an egg), we must *double* the size of our contemporary eggs.  (Original text of the Nodeh B'Yehuda can be found below.)

- Why do they think that we need to *double* the size?

  - Where do they come up with that number?
- Why isn't a *k'zayit* simply the size of an *olive?*

---

Nodeh B'Yehuda - צל"ח מסכת פסחים דף קטז עמוד ב

> ובלילה זו צריכין לאכול כזית מצה וכן מרור ולשתות מן ארבע כוסות רביעית של תורה, צריך אני לברר שיעור הכזית ושיעור הרביעית מה שעולה לדעתי שנתברר לי במופת שהוא שלא כדברי הש"ע, כי באמת מבואר בש"ע סימן תפ"ו ששיעור כזית הוא חצי ביצה.**#** ואמנם לפי שנתברר לי עפ"י מדידה שהביצות המצויות עתה בימינו, הנה הביצה שלימה שבזמנינו הוא רק חצי ביצה מביצים שבהם שיעורי התורה. והמופת הזה כי שיעור חלה הוא מ"ג ביצים וחומש, והתיו"ט מדד שהוא פינט מדה ישנה שמצאתי כאן בבואי לפראג, ואני מדדתי ומצאתי שהוא פחות מפינט, ושוב עשיתי כלי המחזיק שבע אגודלים פחות ב' תשיעית באורך ורוחב ורום מרובע שהוא שיעור חלה המפורש בש"ע בי"ד סימן שכ"ד, והוא על פי חשבון של שיעור מקוה, והכלי זה מחזיק מעט יותר משמנה זיידלך שהוא שני פינט, ואם כן שני שיעורי חלה מכחישים זה את זה, ושניהם הלכה למשה מסיני, כי שיעור מ"ג ביצים וחומש הוא הלכה למשה מסיני, וכן שיעור מקוה הוא הלכה למשה מסיני, ועל כרחך שנשתנה בזמנינו, או שההאגודלים נתגדלו והמה גדולים יותר מהאגודלים שהיו בימי התנאים, או שהביצים נתקטנו והמה בזמנינו קטנים ממה שהיו בימי התנאים. וידוע שהדורות הולכים ומתמעטים ואי אפשר שאגודל שלנו גדול יותר מאגודלים שהיו בימי חכמי ש"ס. ועל כרחך הביצים בזמנינו נתמעטו. ולכן אני מזהיר שעל פינט קמח יקח החלה בלי ברכה, כי לא באתי להקל על שיעורא של התיו"ט, אבל ברכה לא יברכו עד שיהיה שני פינט קמח מחוקים ומעט יותר. וכיון שנתברר שהביצים שלנו נתקטנו על מחציתם, אם כן שיעור זית שהוא חצי ביצה הוא כביצה שלנו. וכזה אשער באכילת מצה ומרור בכל שיעורי התורה. ושיעור רביעית של תורה על פי מדה זו הוא יותר מרובע זיידל של הזיידל הישן שמצאתי פה ק"ק פראג, ובזיידל יש ג' רביעית ומחצה מרביעית של תורה לערך, ופורתא לא דייקינן לחומרא.

<sub>**#** Actually, what it says is *"As for the size of a k'zayis ‬- there are those who say (יש אומרים) that it is half an egg,"* which apparently refers to *tosfos.*  The SA himself does not define the size of a *kezayith.*  (SA 486)</sub>

Comment: Also, if anyone knows the source for the Chazon Ish, I'd be most appreciative.

Comment: Did you look up the Yad Eliyahu Siman 26 and 27

Comment: See Chazon Ish 39:17

Comment: Also see the Tzlach on Pesachim daf 109 The Tzlach did an experiment

Comment: Tzlach on Pesachim 109 doesn't talk about this.  Maybe you meant Pesachim 116?  In which case, see above.

Comment: @sam - If you're viewing it online, could you copy-paste the relevant quote so I can look it up?  For Tzlach on 109 I've got "אמר רב אשי שלחן של מקדש של פרקים הוה וכו' אמתא באמתא היכי מטבליה" and " ולא יפחתו לו מארבעה כוסות, היכי מתקני רבנן מידי דאתי בה לידי סכנה וכו'" neither of which talk about this.

Comment: That's strange the gemara is on 109 there might be two tzlachs ,I don't have the text in front of me,what's the problem he explains why he believes the shuir is diff because of experiment.

Comment: http://www.zootorah.com/RationalistJudaism/TheEvolutionOfTtheOlive.pdf

Comment: @sam - It appears the Tzlach is on different dapim in different editions.  The above PDF says it's on daf 120, Bar Ilan says 116, and you've got 109...

Comment: OK, if I understand correctly, the Tosfos Yom Tov once measured the shiur of Challah (based on מ"ג ביצים וחומש) as "**1** Prague Pint," and then the Tzlach measured it again (based on ז' אצבעות פחות ב' תשיעיות אצבע), and it came out to "**2** Prague Pints." Therefore, it *must be* that either the eggs are half the Talmudic size, or the Tzlach's fingers are twice the Talmudic size. And heaven-forfend that the Tzlach has fat fingers, or that he (or the Tosfos Yom Tov) measured wrong, or that the "Prague Pint" isn't standardized and has changed. Therefore we must **double** everything. Wonderful.

Comment: Well, I guess that contradicts my answer here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18366/how-was-kashrut-affected-by-science

Comment: @DoubleAA - Great article.

Answer (score 4):

Rabbi Natan Slifkin has an extensive presentation of all the different sides of the kezayis discussion [here](http://www.zootorah.com/RationalistJudaism/TheEvolutionOfTtheOlive.pdf). He brings many opinions that actually do hold that the correct size of the kezayis is the actual size of an olive:

> R. Chaim of Volozhin (1749-1821) is widely revered as  the father of
>   the yeshivah world. Less known and certainly less popular in the 
>   yeshivah world is his view as to the size of the matzah that one is
>   obligated to eat  on Pesach. R. Chaim was of the view that this
>   kezayis is actually the size of an  olive—around three or four cubic
>   centimeters.

As far as why the size seems to have increased he says:

> It is in Ashkenaz that we find the olive beginning to evolve with the
>   statements  of the Rishonim themselves (as opposed to with later
>   mistaken inferences  regarding the Rishonim). The Rishonim of Ashkenaz
>   translated the size of an olive  into a proportion of an egg, but they
>   gave different quantities. This was based on  differing resolutions of
>   various passages in the Talmud. In one place, the Talmud  states that
>   a person can swallow food up to the size of two olives:  The Sages
>   evaluated that the throat cannot hold more than two olives. (Talmud, 
>   Krisus 14a)  Elsewhere, the Talmud states that a person can swallow
>   food up to the size of an  egg:  The Sages evaluated that the throat
>   cannot hold more than a chicken’s egg.  (Talmud, Yoma 80a)  These
>   passages indicate that an olive is half the size of an egg. However,
>   in a  third place, a different conclusion emerges. The Talmud (Eruvin
>   82b) discusses the  amount of food required for an eruv. Two of the
>   views cited express their opinion  in terms of kabin, which in turn
>   can be expressed in quantities of eggs (since 1 kav  is 24 eggs):  
>   Rabbi Shimon: Two meals are 2/9 of a kav, which is 5 1/3 eggs.  
>   Rabbi Yochanan ben Beruka: Two meals are ¼ of a kav, which is 6 eggs. 
>   Elsewhere, the Talmud states that two meals are equal to 18 dried
>   figs.  Now, as we saw earlier, an olive is known to be smaller than a
>   dried fig. This results   in the following calculation:   Rabbi
>   Shimon: Two meals = 5 1/3 eggs = 18 dried figs; thus 1 olive is less
>   than  3/10 of an egg   Rabbi Yochanan ben Beruka: Two meals = 6 eggs
>   = 18 dried figs; thus 1 olive  is less than 1/3 of an egg  How are all these sources to be reconciled?

Comment: Though Avrohom Chaim Noeh claims that the Sefardi poskim hold like him in shiur kezais, which while smaller than the Nodeh BeYehuda is larger than the shiur of R' Chaim of Volozhin

Answer (score 1):

There are several basic views as to the size of a kzayis:

1) The most commonly accepted view in the modern works on hilchos brachos (V'zos Habracha, The Halachos of Kzayis by Rabbi Bodner, and others) is that of the Mishna Berura and many other Acharonim. They hold that a Kzayis is either 1/2 (or 1/3) of the volume of the average egg. That is about 1 fluid ounce. The assumption is that the size of an egg is more consistent over the centuries than the size of olives. (The Mishna Berura also recommends one avoid the grey area between 1/2 and 1/3 egg.)

2) Another view, held by Rabbi Chaim Kanievsky, Shlita, is that a kzayis is literally the volume of an olive. This view is generally not followed, partially due to the rule of "safek brachos l'hakel" - one should not say a Bracha unless it is clearly neccesary.

3) The Noda B'Yehuda's view is that a kzayis is about 2 fluid ounces, using a finger-based measurement from the Talmud. This view is generally only followed when there is a Torah-based obligation to eat, like the kzayis we eat on Seder night.

Comment: "held by Rabbi Chaim Kanievsky, Shlita" Where does he rule this way?

Comment: @DoubleAA See the Teshuva printed in the back of The Halachos of K'zayis by R' Y P Bodner.