# Have the measurements for tumah changed throughout the ages?

Tags: shiurim-measurements, maseches-keilim

There is discussion among *poskim* whether we measure a *kezayit* (and other measurements) using contemporary olives/eggs/etc, or whether we use some larger measurement based on a perceived historical reality. See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37636/where-does-the-contemporary-measurement-of-a-kezayit-come-from), for example, or [here](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Reference_of_Measurements_in_Halacha) (with footnotes).

There are measurements for *tumah* as well, such as the pomegranate-sized hole in a utensil used for storing food that makes it no longer susceptible to *tumah*. This measurement is listed in mishnah [Keilim 17:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Kelim.17.5?lang=bi) right next to the *kebeitsa* (in 17:6) and the *kezayit* (in 17:8) (along with the *kegerogeret* and the *amma*).

According to those who believe that the historical reality was different, would we measure holes today in utensils according to that historical reality? Or perhaps, since a pomegranate-sized hole is one that makes the utensil unfit for its purpose, we should measure according to modern sizes, even according to those who say differently for eggs and olives?

Comment: Great question. While we do find in other places (like Nezikin) that sometimes an argument is explained as "actually that don't argue - it depended on where they lived", in Keilim (and Tumah in general) I do not recall any argument being explained this way. Au contraire, IIRC, these sizes are mostly explained as "Halocho L'Moshe MiSinai" and are therefore immutable. Going to keep this in mind and try to prove/disprove as I review the Mishnayot for the 19th time.

Comment: Sukkah 6a implies this would be like the other fruit measurements.