# What's the Shiur of Mashehu?

Tags: shiurim-measurements, chametz-leaven, bitul-batel-null

Certain *issurim* (forbidden things) can become *batel* (halachically nullified) if they were unintentionally mixed in *heter* (permitted things). In order for this to happen, the *heter* must outnumber the *issur* . Depending on what the *issur* is, the necessary measurement may be 1/60 (taste), 1/100 (*terumah*) 1/200 (*kilayei hakerem* and *orla*) or just a simple *rov* (majority).

However some things "never" become *batel*; they are *assur* even *b'mashehu*, that is, even in the smallest amount. The classic example of this is *chametz* (leaven) on Pesach, which is *assur* even in the minutest proportions.

However, I have been told by a Rov that even *mashehu* has a *shiur* (measurement) in which it becomes *batel*. The example I heard was that the Kinneret's water does not all become assur just because someone dumped chametz there on Pesach. (Yes, I'm aware that some are *machmir* on this, but let's leave that out, shall we?)

---

**What is this *shiur*? Is it just a vague "whole lot" kind of feeling? Has any Rov quantified it, or said that it cannot be thus quantified?**

Related: [tap water on Pesach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6630/tap-water-on-pesach) (Specifically [Shalom's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6631/883))

Comment: similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14811/759

Comment: I'm not sure about your specific case, but there is a disagreement among the Poskim if a Mashehu from a mixture that was Assur BeMashehu falls into something else, if that second thing is also Assur. Google " תרי משהוין לא אמרינן". Also, I didn't read the whole thing, but it looks like this Ha'arah may help you out: http://www.haoros.com/Archive/index.asp?kovetz=833&cat=3&haoro=3

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/28589

Comment: isnt this a mefurash gemara in beitzah

Answer (score -1):

R' Blumenkranz in his Pesach Guide discusses homeopathic solutions, and is *mattir* based on them statistically not containing a single molecule. So according to him, a single molecule constitutes *mashehu*. E.g. *mashehu chametz* on pesach of table vinegar is 9.58×10<sup>-44</sup> oz, considering only the the acetic acid part.

Comment: Does he say that if they contained a molecule they would be assur? Or is he only saying that there isn't a molecule to _avoid_ having to deal with mashehu?

Comment: When we are talking about bitul, we are discussing proportions. For example, bitul b'rov requires majority kosher, while bitul b'shishim requires 60 parts kosher to one part non-kosher. Are you attempting to contradict the premise of this question which says that there is some shiur in which *mashehu* becomes batel?

Comment: Also what do you mean by "*statistically* not containing a single molecule"?

Comment: @HodofHod Good point. I will go and take a closer look. However, the question was on how much a _mashehu_ is. Surely a molecule is _mashehu_, and less than that cannot be for particle-physical reasons.

Comment: @Daniel _Mashehu_ is not a proportion, it is a _shiur_: the minimum amount which is assur. Just like a _kezayis_ pork is _assur mid'oraysa_. (Let's not get into _chezi shiur_...) Statistically: E.g. If you have a single molecule _chametz_ floating around in a cup water, and you take out a drop, the _chametz_ will likely remain in the cup, but it just may have been in the drop you took out.

Comment: @NBZ 2 things. First of all: Suppose you somehow know that there is exactly one chametz molecule in a cup of water, and you pour out 50.01% of the water. Does that mean that there is now statistically no chametz in the water? Second of all: is there even such a thing as a molecule of chametz? There is no such thing, for example, as a molecule of flour. Flour is made up of various chemicals which together make chametz, but separately could go into non-chametz things. So if you take a molecule of that chemical, does it matter if you took it from flour?

Comment: @Daniel 1. Not "no chametz", 50.01% chance that there isn't any. A related question could be: "How sure do you have to be in Judaism generally? E.g. that there is no chametz, that you didn't scratch your hair, that you are not a mamzer..." 2. Yes. (Flour actually isn't chametz. See Blumenkrantz for a scientific definition.) A certain chametz is fermented wheat, i.e. alcohol, which is uniformly consisting of (water and) chametz ethanol molecules, CH3CH2OH. Further fermentation gives vinegar, of which a single acetic acid molecule, CH3COOH, is identifiable as chametz.