# Are "mudra" considered to be idolatry?

Tags: avodah-zarah

Mudra (pronounced "moo-druh") is a hand gesture used in some forms of meditation. Wikipedia says that [mudra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mudra) are from Hindu and Buddhist traditions, and based on the information here, it sounds like there might be elements of avodah zarah (idolatry) here.

Is positioning one's hand in specific ways during meditation problematic, if they're following guidance according to these mudras without specific intent towards Buddhism or Hinduism?

Comment: You can technically extend this question to Yoga forms as well

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8713/is-practicing-yoga-against-torah and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53923/alternative-treatment-medicines